# ARKit3 Hardware Requirement Clarification

Tags: ios, ipad, camera, augmented-reality, arkit

On Apple's ARKit 3 page (https://developer.apple.com/augmented-reality/arkit/) there is fine print reading, "People Occlusion and the use of motion capture, simultaneous front and back camera, and multiple face tracking are supported on devices with A12/A12X Bionic chips, ANE, and TrueDepth Camera."

I read this sentence as a computer scientist, which suggests that the device must have an A12, ANE, *and* a TrueDepth camera to support any of "people occlusion, motion capture, simultaneous front/back camera, and multiple face tracking." If this is the case, then the only iPad that can use any of these features is the latest iPad Pro, and *not* an Air, which have an A12, but not a TrueDepth camera. (Sidenote: what is ANE? I can't find documentation on it, but I think it has something to do with the machine learning system.) Is this correct--that only the iPad Pro supports any of these features?

I ask because people occlusion is incredibly important for a multi-user experience around a table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ANE is the *Apple Neural Engine*.

Apple's footnote is a little misleading. People occlusion is performed on the scene captured by the rear camera and so does not make use of the TrueDepth camera.

Multiple face tracking requires a TrueDepth camera, in addition to an A12 chip with ANE.

People occlusion is available on all A12 devices - see [this WWDC session](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/604/?time=545) so the new iPad Air will support it.

Comment: That makes sense. Will motion capture/body tracking also work on an iPad with an A12, but no depth camera? The features seems to be lumped with the others, but I don't think it has anything to do with the depth camera.

Comment: Correct. Body detection and motion capture are performed by the ANE using images captured by the rear camera. Face tracking uses the TrueDepth camera.